# Xamarin.FormsCustom Renderer (Checkbox) size

Tags: checkbox, xamarin.forms

I followed this article ...

```
https://alexdunn.org/2018/04/10/xamarin-tip-build-your-own-checkbox-in-xamarin-forms/
```

to add a checkbox control to Xamarin.forms. It works well, but I cannot figure out how to resize it.

Details:
I have a layout with a rowspan=2 cell spanning two regular cell heights. I get a tiny checkbox sitting in the center of the rowspan, with lots of unused space around it, and users find it is hard to hit when tapping. Therefore I want it double its size according to rowspan=2.

Any idea how I can accomplish this?

**Edit1: Checkbox XAML**

```
        <ctrls:Checkbox 
               Grid.Row="0"
               Grid.Column="2"
               Grid.RowSpan="2"
               OutlineColor="#AFCB08"
               CheckColor="#AFCB08"
               HorizontalOptions="End" 
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               WidthRequest="50"
               HeightRequest="50"
               IsChecked="{Binding Done}" 
               CheckedCommand="{Binding CheckedCommand}" />
```

(Including Senthamizh suggestion to try WidthRequest and HeightRequest)

tried several Values for width and height: 10,50,100. Observations: in no case the checkbox would enlarge. When I used "10", the checkbox collapsed into a vertical line. Playing with DEFAULT_SIZE in CheckBoxRenderer.cs never had any notable effect.

Comment: Did you try changing this `private const int DEFAULT_SIZE = 28;` variable's value in AndroidCheckboxRenderer.cs and iOSCheckboxRenderer.cs files.?!

Comment: Yes, I did, but 
- this would not be XAML
- it had no effect anyway.

Comment: In XAML file., the values for 'WidthRequest' and 'HeightRequest' are getting bound from cs file., so you would rather try changing directly in XAML file then. Did you.?!

Comment: Now thats tricky. Bound this CustomRenderer component with Height & WidthRequest as "FillandExpand"., inside a separate StackLayout and try to resize this layout as your wish. Like this 

`<stacklayout HeightRequest = "25" WidthRequest = "25">
    <ctrls:Checkbox WidthRequest = "FillandExpand" HeightRequest = "FillandExpand" />
</stacklayout> `